# Difference of inner product space of two vectors

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products

If in an inner product space $\alpha,\beta$ are two vectors such that $\|\alpha\|= 2,\|\beta\|=3$, and $\|\alpha+\beta\|=5$. Then $\|\alpha-\beta\|$ is equal to ?

The options are 
1)0 
2)1
3)√10
4)√12

Comment: Also, what would be the approach to solve this one.If α,β are two vectors in a real inner product space such that ||α+β|| = 5
Then  ||α-β|| = 3, then (α/β) is equal to ?

Comment: Do you notice $\|\alpha+\beta\| = \|\alpha\| + \|\beta\|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general connection between the inner product and the norm called the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

First, every inner product space has an induced norm which satisfies the parallelogram law:
$$2\|\mathbf{u}\|^2 + 2\|\mathbf{v}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\|^2 + \|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^2.$$
From this, you can find $\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|$, given $\|\mathbf{u}\|$, $\|\mathbf{v}\|$, and $\|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\|$.

Conversely, every normed vector space with a norm that satisfies the parallelogram law has an induced inner product given by the following polarization identity (over $\mathbb{R}$, with some slight modifications for $\mathbb{C}$)
$$\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\left(\|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\|^2 - \|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^2\right).$$
This will allow you find $\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle$ for any vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ given the norms $\|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\|$ and $\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|$.

Answer (score 0):

notice that $|| \alpha || +|| \beta || = || \alpha + \beta || $.
think about the triangle's inequality where it's edges are the three vectors above. since $ || \alpha + \beta || = || \alpha || +|| \beta ||$ we only have 1 edge in the triangle. this means that  $|| \alpha - \beta|| = | || \alpha || -|| \beta || | = |2-3|=1.